# Regex match depending on lookbehind match

Tags: regex

I need to match these values:

(First approach to a regex that roughly does what I want)

```
\d+([.,]\d{3})*[.,]\d{2}
```

like

```
24,56
24.56
1.234,56
1,234.56
1234,56
1234.56
```

but I need to *not* match

```
1.234.56
1,234,56
```

So somehow I need to check the last occurrence of "`.`" or "`,`" to not be the same as the previous "`.`" or "`,`".

Background: Amounts shall be matched in English and German format with (optional) 1000-Separators.

But even with help of regex101 I completely fail at coming up with a correctly working look-behind. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

UPDATE

Based on the answers I got so far, I came up with this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WonJcY/1)):

```
\d{1,3}(?:([\.,'])?\d{3})*(?!\1)[\.,\s]\d{2}
```

But it matches for example `1234.567,23` which is not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture the digit grouping symbol and use a negative lookahead with a backreference to restrict the decimal separator:

```
^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:([.,])\d{3})*)(?!\1)[.,]\d{2}$
                  ^    ^        ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WonJcY/3)

Group 1 will contain the last value of the digit grouping symbol and `(?!\1)[.,]` will match the other symbol.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:([.,])\d{3})*)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\d+`  - 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits,
  - `(?:([.,])\d{3})*` - zero or more sequences of:

    - `([.,])` - Group 1 capturing `.` or `,`
    - `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `(?!\1)[.,]` - a `.` or `,` but not equal to what was last captured with `([.,])` pattern above
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Pretty close. Good point with \d{1,3} but if I use that, then the 100-separator isn't optional any more. (It won't match `1234,56` )

Comment: Then you can use [`^(?:\d{1,3}(?:([.,])\d{3})*|\d+)(?!\1)[.,]\d{2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Vd6xPK/1)

Comment: D'ough! A simple "or" ... of course! Thank you **so** much! I was beginning to see the matrix ...

Comment: Note that placing `\d+` as the first alternative makes the pattern more efficieint.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^\d+(([.,])\d{3})*(?!\2)[.,]\d{2}$
```

[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZcsd7/1/)